# How to cleanly specify a resolve property for a route

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I want to find a clean way to set `resolve` for a route.

From what I've seen there's 3 main ways of doing this:

- declaring global functions (not good)
- anonymous functions (bad if the logic is complicated or if I need the same function in multiple places)
- setting a method on the controller function (this doesn't work for me because I don't like having controllers as separate function declarations, instead I just do `module(...).controller(...);`

Is there a better way to do this then the above, especially if I need a resolve shared between similar routes. (e.g. /people and /people/:personID)

Thanks.

Comment: Expose the resolve method using a service.

Comment: @Chandermani you can't inject a service during Angular's ".config" phase

Comment: You can for the route object map. Something like `resolve: { data:function($http, $myService) {}}`

Comment: @Chandermani ok, I see what you mean.

Comment: You should make an answer of of this, it seems like the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

How about creating a `.constant` and inject it during your `.config` phase?  If you look at [AngularJS documentation for .constant](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide), you will see that you can define a function as a constant.

So, you should be able to do something like:

```
app.constant("Resolver", {
  "MessageUtils": function () {
    return {
      get: function (message) {
        return "MUTIL: " +  message;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Then you would use it as:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, Resolver) {
  $routeProvider.when("/home", {templateUrl: ..., resolve: Resolver, ...})
...
```

Here is a working plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/psuYHu4rtlp4o42ZgqVs?p=preview

I had a similar request in my [angularAMD](http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/) project and I created a function called `.route` to help me set the resolve property when defining routes.  Here is a [link](https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD/blob/master/src/angularAMD.js#L94) to the code.

Comment: Thanks, marcoseu. Chandermani's idea of using a service or more generic type of provider is broader.